# VueJS Build using .env always results in error

Tags: node.js, vue.js, node-modules

I'm new to VueJS and building using .env files but I decided to give it a try and it gave me this result:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/<user>/workspace/<project-name>/production' in '/Users/<user>/workspace/<project-name>'
```

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong and Google isn't of any help either. I tried to create `production` folder inside my project folder but that also didn't help. What am I doing wrong?

What I did was:

Create the following files

```
.env
.env.development
.env.production
```

Then I ran the command:

```
npm run build --mode production
```

Comment: Seems like some module is requesting /production (entry point script) before build time

Comment: How could I figure out which module that is?

Comment: The error is clearly because /production, so what it this file? Why is it called? Where you define to build inside production?

Comment: There is no /production present anywhere. I have my .env.production and I think that, that is causing the issue. That's the only place where it's defined.